# Integral |z|^2 dz over a contour?

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, complex-integration

> Compute the integral $\int_\gamma|z|^2\,\mathrm dz$ where $\gamma$ is the contour starting at $0$, going vertically to $i$, then going horizontally to $i + 1$, then going vertically to $1$, then, finally, going horizontally to $0$.

I think i need to parameterise the contours but I'm not sure how?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. [Here's a MathJax Tutorial !](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A natural way of parametrizing the first part of that contour (going from $0$ to $i$ vertically) is to define $\gamma(t)=it$ ($t\in[0,1]$). And$$\int_\gamma|z|^2\,\mathrm dz=\int_0^1|it|^2i\,\mathrm dt=i\int_0^1t^2\,\mathrm dt=\frac i3.$$Can you do the rest?

Comment: Thank you very much, that is very helpful! so am I right in saying that the second part of the contour should be $$ \gamma(t)=(i+1)t $$ and when integrated gives $2i/3$? And in total i calculated the integral as $4i/3 - 1/3$? Thanks for any help!

Comment: @cathc No. The second part should be $\gamma(t)=t+i$, with $t\in[0,1]$, in order to go from $i$ to $1+i$. If my answer was useful, perhaps that you could mark it as the accepted one.

Comment: And the third: $$\gamma(t)=ti+1$$ ?? And the final contour: $$\gamma(t)=t$$ and all are evaluated from 0 to 1, am i correct? Many thanks

Comment: @cathc No. That one goes from $1$ to $1+i$. Take $\gamma(t)=(1-t)i+1$ instead.

Comment: Great thanks. so my final answer was $$-i + 7/3$$